# dojo ajax dropdownlist

Tags: dojo

I am trying to set a web application using ajax dojo technology. For this I need an exemple showing how to send and receive data with dojo library.I  use also J2ee in my project.
Please if you have a constructive example show it to me.
Client side: JSP with ajax dojo its purpose is to send a selected item to the server side.
Server side:Servlet catch the data sent and construct sql query with it finally send it again to jsp
JSP receive the result of the query (xml file)
dojo construct the seceond dropdownlist automaticallt.
Just i need an exemple of send and receive.

Many Thinks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked on Dojo's website? From your question, it sounds like what you want is dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore. The Dojo website has many examples of the uses of ItemFileReadStore, including one in which one FilteringSelect is dependently linked to another, which seems to be what you describe.
As to your request for examples of send and receive in JSP: a Google search for JSP tutorial turns up a site called jsptut.com as the first result. Have you looked there?